# EC2 - New user can't cd into directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, amazon-ec2

I just launched a new EC2 Ubuntu 12.04 instance and created a new linux user then created the user's home directory under `/home` and granted persimmons to that user.

```
$ useradd user
$ groupadd group
$ mkdir /home/user
$ chown -R user:group /home/user
```

Now when I create directory under new user and try to cd to it, I get some strange error

```
user ~ $ mkdir www
user ~ $ cd www
sh: 1: cd: can't cd to www
```

Any ideas as to what `sh: 1: cd: can't cd to www` means and how I can fix?

Comment: Can you paste the output of ls -l /home/user ?

Comment: I'm curious, why use 'useradd'?  'adduser' is the recommended command according to the 'useradd' man page.